# Hide and Display text on a click function (HTML, CSS, JS)

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm currently developing a website with bootstrap and I'm trying to build a function to show and hide a text whenever I click on a thumbnail, without the need to load another page.

It would be ideal to have some kind of a "radio type input" to toggle between the contents shown through clicks on the thumbnails.

[image: Website]

Beneath the sidebar are the thumbnails and on the right is the main content.
I'd like the page to have the text as a "placeholder" and whenever i click on a thumbnail with a image, the image should appear replacing the text shown as the main content.

At the moment if i click on a thumbnail it looks like this.

[image]

I'll keep on trying by myself but i'd be really grateful if you guys could help me out.

Stay safe and healthy!

```js
function myFunction(imgs) {
  var expandImg = document.getElementById("expandedImg");
  var imgText = document.getElementById("imgtext");
  expandImg.src = imgs.src;
  imgText.innerHTML = imgs.alt;
  expandImg.parentElement.style.display = "block";
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Christoph Urwalek - The Twin Tower of Arts</title>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../assets/css/style.css">
  <link href="../../assets/css/i20.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="../assets/js/ubertooltip.js"></script>
</head>


<body onLoad="loadTip()">
  <!-- START Mobile Nav-->
  <header>
    <nav class="d-xl-none headerMenu navbar fixed-top" onclick="openNav()">
      &#9776;
      <h5 id="headerLogo">Christoph Urwalek</h5>
    </nav>
  </header>
  <div id="myNav" class="overlay">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
    <div class="overlay-content">
      <a href="../canvaswork/painting.html">painting</a>
      <a href="../paperwork/drawing.html">drawing</a>
      <a href="../collagework/collage.html">collage</a>
      <a href="../videowork/video.html">video</a>
      <br>
      <br>
      <a href="../current/aktuell.html">current</a>
      <a href="../text/text.html">text</a>
      <a href="../biography/bio.html">biography</a>
      <a href="../contact/impressum.html">contact</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- END Mobile Nav-->
  <!--START Wrapper-->
  <div class="container-fluid my-container align-items-center">
    <!--START Sidebar -->
    <div class="row my-row">
      <div class="col-md-3 ">
        <nav class="sidebar-header sidebar">

          <li><a href="../index.html"><b>Christoph Urwalek</b></a></li>
          <br>
          <li><a href="../canvaswork/painting.html">painting</a></li>
          <li><a href="../paperwork/drawing.html">drawing</a></li>
          <li><a class="active" href="../collagework/collage.html">collage</a></li>
          <li><a href="../videowork/video.html">video</a></li>
          <li>
            <a> </a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="../current/aktuell.html">current</a></li>
          <li><a href="../text/text.html">text</a></li>
          <li><a href="../biography/bio.html">biography</a></li>
          <li><a href="../contact/impressum.html">contact</a></li>
          <br>

          <div class="thumbnailContainer">
            <img href="/collagework/the_twin_towers_of_arts_in_education.html" src="../assets/img/The Twin Towers of Arts in Education/TextLogo.png" alt="" class="img-thumbnail border-0 img-thumbnail-desktop">
            <img src="../assets/img/The Twin Towers of Arts in Education/Art-Education-Tower-01__.jpg" alt="" class="img-thumbnail border-0 img-thumbnail-desktop" onclick="myFunction(this);">
            <img src="../assets/img/The Twin Towers of Arts in Education/Art-Education-Tower-02__.jpg" alt="###" class="img-thumbnail border-0 img-thumbnail-desktop" onclick="myFunction(this);">
            <img src="../assets/img/The Twin Towers of Arts in Education/Art-Education-Tower-03__.jpg" alt="###" class="img-thumbnail border-0 img-thumbnail-desktop" onclick="myFunction(this);">
          </div>
          <!--END Thumbnaill Navbar-->
          <div>
        </nav>
        </div>
        <!--END Sidebar -->
        <!--START Wandcollage-->
        <div class="col-md-9 ">
          <!--main content-->
          <p class="text-justify textMargin ">
            <b>The Twin Towers of Arts in Education</b><br><br> Siebdruck auf Papier, 95 x 65 cm, 2013<br><br> Die Displays veranschaulichen in Diagrammstruktur Perspektiven künstlerischer Handlungsformen in Bildungsprozessen unterschiedlicher Partikularkulturen.
            Jede Ebene der beiden Türme repräsentiert einen Konzeptrahmen, der Diskursformen mittels vier Axiomen zeigt: Reproduktion, Affirmation, Dekonstruktion und Transformation. Der linke Turm repräsentiert Wissensproduktion in künstlerischen Prozessen,
            während der rechte Turm Wissensproduktion in analogen Bildungsprozessen repräsentiert. Die Konzeptrahmen in den Türmen bewegen sich zwischen kontextellen Strukturen und gesellschaftlichen Strukturen. Alle Eckpunkte der jeweiligen Axiome sind
            entsprechend miteinander verbunden und stehen sich im Kommunikationsprozess kritisch gegenüber. Zwischen den beiden Türmen befindet sich die Achse der Kritikalität. Sie ist vermittelnd verbunden mit den einzelnen Diskursformen. Auf ihr entsteht
            die Perspektive eines Gegenbewusstseins, das die Achse des vorherrschenden Bewusstseins in einem transformativen Lernprozess durchkreuzt. Die Arbeit orientiert sich an Stephen Willats Konzeption eines Parameter Modells, das zwischen unterschiedlichen
            existierenden und möglichen ideologischen Konzeptrahmen vermittelt.
          </p>
          <div class="container expandedImgSize d-flex justify-content-center ">
            <span onclick="this.parentElement.style.display='none'"></span>
            <img class="img-fluid" id="expandedImg" src="">
            <div id="imgtext">
              <!--TEXT EINFÜGEN-->
            </div>
          </div>
          <!--section-->
          <div class="d-xl-none">
            <div id="firstThumbnail" class="mobileGallery thumbnail d-flex justify-content-center imagePreview">
              <a href="">
                <img src="../assets/img/collection/Collection-Montage-01_.jpg" alt="" style="width:400px;">
                <div class="caption">
                  <p id="captionStyle">Collection, Performance, &copy; Barbara Höller<br>2013</p>
                </div>
              </a>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!--section-->
          <!--section-->
          <div class="d-xl-none">
            <div id="firstThumbnail" class="mobileGallery thumbnail d-flex justify-content-center imagePreview">
              <a href="">
                <img src="../assets/img/collection/Collection_.jpg" alt="" style="width:400px;">
                <div class="caption">
                  <p style="margin-top: 5px;" id="captionStyle">
                    Collection, Performance, &copy; Christian Helbock<br> 2013
                  </p>
                </div>
              </a>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!--section-->
          <!--section-->
          <div class="d-xl-none">
            <div id="firstThumbnail" class="mobileGallery thumbnail d-flex justify-content-center imagePreview">
              <a href="">
                <img src="../assets/img/collection/Collection-Performance-10_.jpg" alt="" style="width:400px;">
                <div class="caption">
                  <p id="captionStyle">Collection, Performance, &copy; Barbara Höller<br>2013</p>
                </div>
              </a>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!--section-->
          <!--section-->
          <div class="d-xl-none">
            <div id="firstThumbnail" class="mobileGallery thumbnail d-flex justify-content-center imagePreview">
              <a href="">
                <img src="../assets/img/collection/Collection-Performance-13_.jpg" alt="" style="width:400px;">
                <div class="caption">
                  <p id="captionStyle">Collection, Performance, &copy; Barbara Höller<br>2013
                  </p>
                </div>
              </a>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!--section-->
          <!--section-->
          <div class="d-xl-none">
            <div id="firstThumbnail" class="mobileGallery thumbnail d-flex justify-content-center imagePreview">
              <a href="">
                <img src="../assets/img/collection/Collection-Performance-15_.jpg" alt="" style="width:400px;">
                <div class="caption">
                  <p id="captionStyle">Collection, Performance, &copy; Barbara Höller
                    <br>2013</p>
                </div>
              </a>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!--section-->
          <!--section-->
          <div class="d-xl-none">
            <div id="firstThumbnail" class="mobileGallery thumbnail d-flex justify-content-center imagePreview">
              <a href="">
                <img src="../assets/img/collection/Collection-Performance-16_.jpg" alt="" style="width:400px;">
                <div class="caption">
                  <p id="captionStyle">Collection, Performance, &copy; Barbara Höller
                    <br>2013</p>
                </div>
              </a>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!--section-->
          <!--section-->
          <div class="d-xl-none">
            <div id="firstThumbnail" class="mobileGallery thumbnail d-flex justify-content-center imagePreview">
              <a href="">
                <img src="../assets/img/collection/Collection-Montage-02_.jpg" alt="" style="width:400px;">
                <div class="caption">
                  <p id="captionStyle">Zusammenarbeit (Together), Montage: &copy; Christian Helbock<br> 2013</p>
                </div>
              </a>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!--section-->
        </div>
        <!-- d-xl-none -->
        <!--section-->
      </div>
      <!--col-md-9-->
    </div>
  </div>
  <!--END Wrapper-->
  <script src="../assets/js/main.js">
  </script>
  <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
  <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: So what I'm getting at you want the thumbnails, when you click them to replace the `placeholder` text?

Comment: If so set the style display to `none` when you click a specific thumbnail for the class set for that element to hide the placeholder text

Comment: what do you think is the best way to express such a function?

Comment: Posted an answer you might wanna check it out

Answer (score 0):

Wrote a brief example on how to incorporate a basic image selector.

```js
      function myFunction(img) {
        let currImage = img.target;
        let image = document.querySelector("#expandedImg");
        let textImage = document.querySelector("#imgtext");
        
        textImage.innerText = currImage.alt;
        image.setAttribute('src', currImage.src);
      }
      
      let images = document.querySelectorAll(".thumbnailContainer > img");
      images.forEach((img) => {
          img.addEventListener("mouseover", myFunction, true);
      });
```

```css
     .thumbnailContainer > img {
        cursor: pointer;
      }
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Basic Image Selector</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>

  <div class="thumbnailContainer">
    <img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/344/200/300.jpg?hmac=hFZM-uJoRMyNATe_kjGvS2NGGP60jqqP64vpGQ98VAo" alt="This is Image 1" id="img-thumbnail border-0 img-thumbnail-desktop" />
    <img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/509/200/300.jpg?hmac=Y2Mtq5PEipyaFNlDH01CoNhW9to1T8GCuTf6yUSH-TY" alt="This is Image 2" id="img-thumbnail border-0 img-thumbnail-desktop" />
    <img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/237/200/300.jpg?hmac=TmmQSbShHz9CdQm0NkEjx1Dyh_Y984R9LpNrpvH2D_U" alt="This is Image 3" id="img-thumbnail border-0 img-thumbnail-desktop" />
    <img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/866/200/300.jpg?hmac=rcadCENKh4rD6MAp6V_ma-AyWv641M4iiOpe1RyFHeI" alt="This is Image 4" id="img-thumbnail border-0 img-thumbnail-desktop" />
  </div>

  <img id="expandedImg" />
  <div id="imgtext"></div>

</body>
</html>
```